# selecting next tabbed-to object and problems with constant keydown pressing

Tags: jquery, keydown, keyup

**EDITED AT END**

Selecting next tabbed-to object and problems with constant keydown pressing ..

1. My tabbed-to next object is automatically determined via setting `tabindex = 0` for all required objects (= `li`).
2. When I 1st press TAB (`keydown`), the existing `li` object is still selected. After I release TAB (`keyup`), the next object is selected based on `tabindex = 0`.
3. Okay so far ... when I then press and release TAB again, the new next object is selected.
4. Again OK, so far ... so what's the problem?
5. THE problem centers on a user pressing **and holding TAB**. When the user does this, a `keyup` Event is never registered and an incorrect next object is selected.
6. So, in deference to the possibility of a press and hold Event, I do my coding based on keydown, not keyup.

Here's my previous code, based on a `keyup` Event and this code works great **unless** there is a press and hold:

```
function showMenuWithTabForward() {
    
    var $theMenu;
    
    // = *after* TAB
    // = $(document.activeElement)
    var $currItem = getFocusedItem();
    var $nextLI = $currItem;

    // ...

    $nextLI.focus();

}
```

And here is the code based on a keyup Event:

```
function showMenuWithTabForward() {
    
    var $theMenu;
    
    // = *before* TAB
    var $currItem = getFocusedItem();
    // = *after* TAB
    var $temp = $currItem.find("li").first();
    if ($temp.hasClass("#menubar > li") ||
        $temp.hasClass("drop")          ||
        $temp.hasClass("daddy"))
    {
        $currItem = $temp;
    }

    var $nextLI = $currItem;

    // ...

    $nextLI.focus();

}
```

The problem with is new code is that the next object [`.find("li")`] skips over the correct next object.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Boy, how I wish I could make the changes required for *press and hold with `keyup`* ... not to be, I guess.

**BEGIN EDIT**

*When a key is pressed down, how do I make it act as a `keyup` event?*

IF I can do that, I think I can have my cake and eat it too.

Namely, my `keyup` code works just dandy. Currently, the `keyup` callback is accessed when a keyup Event happens.

Naturally!!

So, how to I make a `keydown` Event behave like a `keyup` Event?

This challenge is definitely **not** just placing the `keyup` code in a `keydown` Handler.

And the reason is that with a `keydown`, the TAB `keypress` hasn't happened yet so the Browser has not selected the next `<li>` object. This selection doesn't happen until just before the `keyup`.

Comment: would you rather prevent the press-and-hold action and only register one event on any given keypress? To me that would seem preferable

Comment: Gotta think about that. For what it's worth, just how do I negate press and hold? This is to say, if I return to `keyup`, just how to I ignore the user's press and hold and do nothing? Creating an empty callback function for `keydown`? Gotta think about that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you were asking for but it's one solution - eliminate the possibility of a keypress-and-hold scenario

```js
let tabOn = true
$('body').on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
  console.log( `attempting ${e.type}`)
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.type === 'keyup') {
      tabOn = true;
      return;
    } else if (e.type === 'keydown' && !tabOn) return
    else if (e.type === 'keydown') tabOn = false;
    console.log('tab')
    // call custom function here
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```